# Integrated Mode In IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8

Microsoft documentation says that "Integrated mode eliminates steps that were previously duplicated in IIS and ASP.NET, such as authentication."

what is meant by this? how authentication was duplicated in previous version of IIS and what is meant by unified pipeline?

Comment: Based on my understand, there was some duplicated authentication configuration like IIS windows authentication(system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication enabled=true) and asp.net windows authentication(system.web/authentication mode=windows). In the past classic mode they are independent.  In Integrated mode, the incoming request only have to be authenticated once.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis Read the diagrams and the meaning should be clear.